# How can I increase values in an array by a percent input by the user? In C#

Tags: c#

So I want to store several values in an array, then I want to modify those values that I stored by a percent that I also input. This is what I have so far, I just don't know how to call the values to be modified by a percent that I input.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    double[] array = new double[5];
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 values.");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        array[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    double sum = 0;

    foreach (double d in array)
    {
        sum += d;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The values you've entered and their index number.");
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1,8}", "index", "value");
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{1,8}", counter, array[counter]);
    Console.WriteLine("Enter percent increase ");

    double percent;
        percent = 1+1;
    Console.WriteLine("The percent is " + percent);

    Console.WriteLine("The new values increased by Percent are ");
    Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Well, you already know how to loop through the values with a `for` loop, and I assume you know how to multiply - are you expecting some method that lets you apply a function to all values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask the numbers as you do:

```
double[] array = new double[5];    
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    array[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Ask for percent:

```
double percent = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // value between 0-100
```

And increase each value of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    array[i] += array[i] * percent / 100.0; // Add the percent
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I have trouble seeing the simplest things sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
double[] result = Array.ConvertAll(array, d => d + d * (percent/100));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `for` loop.

```
var percentage = 1 + percent * 0.01;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   array[i] = array[i] * percentage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, increasing a value by `x%` is equivalent to multiplication by `1+x/100.0`. Decreasing works the same way when `x` is negative.

All you need to do now is iterating the array, and multiplying each number by `1+x/100.0`

Comment: Perhaps an explanation of a downvote may be in order, no?